# Reset Toshiba Satellite C850-B559 Bios/Supervisor Password?

Tags: boot, bios, passwords, toshiba-laptop, reset

Im trying to acces boot option by pressing F12 boot menu key ? But it asks for Supervisor Password which i dont know?
[image]

1.Tried removing the bios battery - doesnt work

2.Downloaded a Toshiba Password Utility but it still ask for current supervisor Password.

So how can i reset the supervisor password ?
I Looked into couple of youtube videos that shows manually resetting the password using jumper on motherboard but couldn't find the exact for this model.

Comment: Did a previous owner of the laptop put the Supervisor password on there? They don't just "happen" spontaneously.

Answer (score 1):

This video solved my problem. But always be careful.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OR7qAigtNMU

Instructions:

1. Tilt your laptop and **short the two contact** as shown in the picture with the wire or screw driver.
2. Then turn on the laptop, keep the contact for few seconds and turn off the laptop.

(I kept both battery and ram inside the laptop while doing this, some of the online resources suggests to remove ram, hard disk, battery and plug in the power then short but i worked for me.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.